# Can't use variables to define color with Pillow

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm getting stuck on a small (I guess) error using Pillow. I'm trying to set the color of my text with a variable but get a ValueError: unknown color specifier: '"232,43,123,255"' when trying it.
Here is my code :

```
header = Image.open("A.png")
couleur_Ellipse = "rose"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(header)
point = ( int(header.width * 0.780), int(header.height * 0.68))
header.paste(ellipse, point, ellipse)
colortext = '"232,43,123,255"'
pointtext1 = ( int(header.width * 0.845), int(header.height * 0.75))
pointtext2 = ( int(header.width * 0.798), int(header.height * 0.79))
draw.text(pointtext1, "this is some text", font=ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", 14), fill=colortext)
draw.text(pointtext2, "some other text", font=ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf", 55), fill=colortext)
header.save('Images/header ' + couleur_Ellipse + '.png')
```

Any insight ? I do not understand why it doesn't work

Comment: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html 
It would seem that you need to provide a colour-function, rather than just a string of values. I assume also that you are using a version of PIL equal to or greater than 1.1.4, so that you can provide an alpha value?

Try without the alpha: colortext = "rgb(232,43,123)"

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. I'm not a native speaker so the documentation is always a bit hard for me to read. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Conversion of Comment into Answer:

cf: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html

According to the documentation, you need to provide a colour-function (or a hex-colour), rather than just a string of values. And, the colour-function provided as a string doesn't seem to support the alpha value.

Try this:

```
colortext = "rgb(232,43,123)"
```